# How to fix ECONNRESET?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, next.js, connection

I'm having trouble developing web apps with Next Js and React Native.
It shows me a connection error due to the line.
npm ERR! code ECONNRESET
npm ERR! syscall read
npm ERR! errno ECONNRESET
npm ERR! network Invalid response body while trying to fetch https://registry.npmjs.org/next: read Econnreset

I have this:[image]

How can fix it?